# how to erase pause in batch file

Tags: batch-file, pause

I'm making a game called the Text Adventure. This is not much of a problem, but I want to know how to remove `Press any key to continue . . .`
after the user presses the key, and not using cls which will also clear the title screen. Any suggestions other that using cls and copy and pasting the title screen?

Comment: I don't understand why people close a question when it already have an answer with a simple solution that solve the question exactly, with no doubts. May someone explain this point, perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get a CR control char
for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"

rem Show the 'pause' message
set /P "=Press any key to continue . . ." < NUL
rem Execute 'pause', but don't show anything on screen
pause > NUL
rem Show a CR and enough number of spaces to delete previous message
set /P "=.!CR!Ready...                        " < NUL
```

Comment: how does `for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"` set a CR?

Comment: Very nice. I didn't think this would work until I tried it.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Mmmm... This method is really old. I couldn't found an explanation of it, but it is used in multiple sites, like [this one](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1733&p=6803#p6803)